Is there any way to use random placeholder for text_input without loosing variable data?
Issue: Streamlit text_input with random placeholder not displaying user input
I am having an issue with my Streamlit app where the user input is not displaying correctly when using a random placeholder. If I use a static placeholder, it works fine. However, when I switch to a random placeholder, whatever input entered by user doesn't get display after clicking button.
Here's my code:
import streamlit as st
import random

placeholders = ["Enter your name", "Type your message", "Say something", "What's on your mind?"]

# Get user input with a random placeholder
user_input = st.text_input("Enter your input:", placeholder=random.choice(placeholders), key='name')

# Create a button to print the user input
if st.button("Greet"):
    if user_input:
        st.write(f"Hello, {user_input}")
    else:
        st.write("please enter input")

Current Output:
please enter input
Expected Output:
Hello, [user input]
I just want to use random placeholder and whatever user will enter it should display when user clicks button.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or can suggest a workaround to use random placeholders for user input in Streamlit?
Thanks in advance!

Debug info:

streamlit==1.37.0
Python 3.11.7


What you're saying doesn't make sense.  The text_input function only knows that it is getting a string object.  It has no clue where it came from.  There must be more to it than this.

the output has nothing to do with the placeholder. It just depends on whether the user filled in the text input.

Are you expecting the placeholder to be used as the default value if the user doesn't enter anything? That's not how placeholders work.

@Barmar i don't want to use placeholder as default value. I just want to use random placeholder and when user enter text and press button it should display the text whatever entered by user.

Your code should do that. If you're going into the else: block it means the user isn't entering anything into the input.

You're asking for input before displaying the button. Move the call to st.text_input() into the first if block.
# Create a button to print the user input
if st.button("Greet"):
    # Get user input with a random placeholder
    user_input = st.text_input("Enter your input:", placeholder=random.choice(placeholders), key='name')
    if user_input:
        st.write(f"Hello, {user_input}")
    else:
        st.write("please enter input")

